# asp.net sql timeout when not using sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Im in the process of learning asp.net 3.5, currently on webparts and co.

Ive started a new project for webparts, not using a database with it, but when i go to view the website (dev server), i get an sql timeout??

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server.

Just to be clear, there is no mention of sql anywhere in the project.
Should i just start again?

**Edit:**
May be relevant

> (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webparts infrastructure talks to a database.

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed, needed to enable/start sql server 2008 express